# VSTest tests fail because of shared folder

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines, vstest, azure-devops-server-2020

We use Azure DevOps Server 2020 to run CI on our 50-ish projects in our solution. We've been upgrading some nugets recently and the VSTest task began to fail on our build server with the exception

> Failed to load assembly or one of its dependencies...

Even though MSTest and ReSharper tests succeeded locally.

After investigating, I've discovered, that one of the top-level projects had a new nuget with transitive dependency to Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.1 while our Core project (which is referenced by all other projects) had explicit reference to Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.3. This works just fine when the tests are run per project, but the VSTest task, for whatever reason, copies all of the project build outputs to one folder which causes some of the DLLs to be overwritten with different versions.

The VSTest task configuration looks like this:
[image: config]

Is this a bug to be reported, a configuration issue, or a "feature"?